# Vuex Modules Mutations

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I need to call vuex module it doesn't work. I've seen the documentation but still it doesn't work. Hope someone can help me.

```
const stateLocations ={

    state: {

        provinces: {},
        cities: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        provinces(state, payload){

            state.provinces = payload
        }
    }
}


const store = new Vuex.Store({

    modules: {
        locations: stateLocations
    }


})
```

My code to call the mutations

```
created(){

            var store = this.$store

            axios.get('api/provinces')
                .then( function(response){

                    store.state.locations.commit('provinces', response.data)
                })
                .catch()
        }
```

This one doesn't work `store.state.locations.commit('provinces', response.data)`
TY

Comment: Offtop but I should note this way of talking with external api is not correct according to vuex docs. Such logic should be moved into `actions` section of the vuex module.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Because you didn't enable `namespaced` in the module, you simply need to

```
this.$store.commit('provinces', response.data)
```

If you want to enable namespace:

```
const stateLocations = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    ...
```

then you commit the mutation like this:

```
this.$store.commit('locations/provinces', response.data)
```